# Java - Regex only 0 or 5

Tags: java, regex

Regular expression only accepts **0** or **5**. 
Is there a regex expression to evaluate that? 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to go actually learn regexes. Asking if a regex can do this is like asking whether Java can add numbers, or asking whether cars can move.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't want to learn regex, I only want to know that. Thanks for subtract me reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `"0|5"` or `"[05]"`. The first is an alternative, the second is a character class. They will behave identically. See the [documentation for `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information on the building blocks for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#character_classes). And use this:

`"^[05]$"`

Comment: The question is tagged `java` and you're referring OP to .NET documentation? Cool.

Comment: @TedHopp Does Regex Language depends on the language you use it in?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych not for such a simple regex, but there are huge diffrences between implementations.

Comment: The basics are pretty much identical, but there are differences. See, e.g., [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401794/differences-in-regex-between-java-net-and-javascript) and especially some of the resources linked to from there.

Comment: @TedHopp didn't know. Thanks for information.